# Trouble with nested if-else statements

Tags: java

I am having problems with nesting some if-else statements, at least that is what I think the problem is. I have butchered this code several times trying to figure it out, so I decided to put it back to the original state and ask for some help.  A user is asked to input an odd number between 3 and 15. I need to validate that input and if it is not between 3 and 15, output an error message. Same goes if it is not an odd number, it needs to output a different number.  When running the code below, if I enter an even number, letter, or number <3 or >15 I get both error messages. If the input is an odd number between 3 and 15, it works fine. I know I have to differentiate between the two errors, just have not been able figure out how to do it and make the code run/work properly. Have also tried else if with no luck. Sure it is something silly, since most of my mistakes seem to be on the silly side. Thanks for your help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare variables
    String inputString;
    boolean done = false;
    int numRows = 0;

    // Prompt for user input  
    do
    {
        inputString = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Enter number of rows (odd number between 3 and 15): ");

        // Validating input
        try
        {
            numRows = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        if(numRows % 2 == 0) // Validating input is an odd number
             done = true; 
        if((numRows < 3) || (numRows > 15))// Validating input is between 3 and 15
            done = true;
        else
            done = false;

        if(done)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, not an ODD number. Re-enter odd number between 3 and 15",
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    

        if(done)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, number not between 3 and 15. Re-enter odd number between 3 and 15",
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    while(done);
    }
```

Comment: Use curly braces with if/else and make your life easier.

Comment: `if((numRows < 3) || (numRows > 15))// Validating input is between 3 and 15`  is doing the opposite of what the comment says

Comment: I don't understand why you don't expect both messages to be printed when `done` is true when you are explicitly printing both of them.

Comment: @Jsdodgers that is my issue. I have tried to separate them without any luck. I ended going back to the original code when asking for some help.

Comment: @Ireeder, saw that and fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interesting thing here is, you don't need the if statements.  You can greatly simplify (and fix) your boolean expressions.

First, let's establish the behavior of `(numRows < 3) || (numRows > 15)`.  For this to be true, either `numRows` has to be strictly less than 3, or strictly greater than 15.  This does not validate a range of numbers - you need to switch this to an AND statement.  But even just doing that doesn't validate the correct range - you'll be validating everything that *isn't* between 3 and 15!

To fix that, you need to flip your inequalities.

You now have `(numRows >= 3) && (numRows <= 15)`.  For this to be true, `numRows` must be between the bounds of 3 and 15, inclusive.

Now, let's combine that with the check for odd/even, and you arrive at this:

```
 done = (numRows % 2 == 0) || ((numRows >= 3) && (numRows <= 15));
```

The behavior of this statement is as such:

- Either `numRows` is an even number, OR
- `numRows` is bound between 3 and 15, inclusive.

I've also got some thoughts on you combining your `JOptionPane` statements as well, but that's more of a presentation issue than a code issue - I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: if I combine them, how do I get the separate error message for the 2 different errors? That is my issue. I can wrap it all up into one error message, however I have to have  the different error messages depending on the error.

Comment: If it's a separate error message, then you have separate booleans controlling each.  `done` is a bit generic and over-used, so if you have `isEven` and `isBounded`, then that would give you what you need.  You'd assign your variables with respect to your conditions.